# fatal error CS0007: Unexpected common language runtime initialization error - the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: .net, codedom, system-codedom-compiler

Please help me in solving the error `fatal error CS0007: Unexpected common language runtime initialization error - the system cannot find the file specified.`

When I dynamically compile (from C# forms application) the code using codedom the above error is thrown. But when I compile the same file from test project no error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While compilation using codedom, I have given the wrong path for the App.config..
After providing the correct path this error disappeared.